# Angular and Django: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: django, angular, html2canvas

I am working with Angular and Django. In angular I am generating reports with jspdf and html2canvas, for this I am loading images stored in Django and at the moment of wanting to generate the pdf I generate the error mentioned in the title. In Django I have added corsheaders and given the permissions to be able to access from Angular:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
'http://localhost:4200',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = list(default_methods) + [
'POKE',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
'my-custom-header',
]
```

The Angular function to generate the pdf:

```
pdf () {
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#content"), {allowTaint : 
true}).then(canvas => {

  var img=new Image(); img.crossOrigin="anonymous"
  img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 10);
    doc.save('test.pdf');
  });
  }
```

Reviewing pages suggested adding the crossOrigin = "anonymous" but this has not worked for me

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: Edited.........